# PHP define in config file does not update with new value

Tags: php, cache

I have just installed a new system and set up the configuration file (DB settings).
the conf' file has the following definitions:

```
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASS', 'pass!');
```

It all works perfectly until we had to change the DB user.
From some reason the PHP keeps the old value although we have change it in the conf' file.

Now, we are getting PHP error when it tries to connect to the mySQL DB, and we can see it's using the old password.

Restarting apache2 service didn't solve it

Comment: I'd look at the code for connecting to the database and make sure it's actually *using* that setting. Someone probably just hardcoded it or there are multiple config files.

Comment: This was the first thing I had in mind but from the PHP code I saw that the connection string does use these settings: `$DB_CON=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);`

Comment: It might be using those settings, but that particular definition of those settings might not be being used. Add this error_log("TEST"); below those definitions and then run it, look in your error log. I bet it won't say TEST.

Comment: How is php being run? mod_php? fastcgi?

Comment: - err log does show "TEST"

Comment: - PHP run as "Apache 2.0 Handler" (according to phpinfo() - Server API)